# How did they get the formulas for Av, Rin, and Rout for this problem?

Tags: bjt, common-base

[image]

How did they get the formulas for Av, Rin, and Rout for both problems?
I understand how they solved it. I just want to know where they got the formulas because I can't seem to find them anywhere. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: An important step that **is not shown** is a drawing of the **small signal equivalent circuit**. Draw that circuit based on the schematic. Then use circuit analysis to get to the expressions. *I understand how they solved it.* No you don't because getting those formulas / expressions is the essential part of the assignment. Anyone can fill in the numbers and calculate the values.

Comment: All 3 formulas are derived from conducting a circuit analysis of the small signal equivalent circuit. Draw the small signal equivalent of this circuit and add the drawing to your question - that'll display your efforts better, and might help you solve the question on your own!

Comment: Also, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1TMV2toj6MA) may help you a lot.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help! I really appreciate it @uriyaba :)

Comment: You're welcome, @Bel :)